# how arrange checkout form fields

Tags: wordpress

i have customized fields some month ago.

for example name and family are at a row, also state and city in same row.

i just forget how i did this, can somebody help me to arrange other fields?

i have disabled all plugin ( except woocommerce ) and changed theme to other one to know where i did changes, but no chance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ACF Plugin? If Yes, there is an option for it (in Field Settings).

```
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font: 1em Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

* {box-sizing: border-box;}

p {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 15em;
  border: 5px solid rgb(111,41,97);
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(111,41,97,.3);
  border: 2px solid rgba(111,41,97,.5);
}
```

```
<h2>Flex</h2>

<div class="container flex">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item">Two Two</div>
  <div class="item">Three Three Three</div>
  <div class="item">Four Four Four Four</div>
</div>

<h2>Grid</h2>

<div class="container grid">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item">Two Two</div>
  <div class="item">Three Three Three</div>
  <div class="item">Four Four Four Four</div>
</div>
```

NOTE use grid class CSS on your parent div, also field need to fill with item class value

Comment: no i have not that plugin. maybe i changed it directly from woocommerece. do you know how do that from woocommerece coding?

Comment: i've disabled all plugins except woocommerece. i'm sure it's related to woocommerece.